# How can I calculate and update bayesian discrete probabilities?

Tags: r, probability, bayesian, updating

I have 100 rows and 5 columns, each row is a sequence of 5 integers between 1 and 3 like

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1   2  2  1  3  1
2   2  1  2  3  2
3   2  3  1  2  2
4   2  3  1  1  3
5   2  1  2  3  1
6   2  1  2  2  2
7   2  2  2  1  2
8   2  1  3  2  2
9   2  2  2  2  2
10  2  2  1  2  3
11  2  3  2  1  1
12  2  1  3  2  1
13  2  1  3  2  3
14  2  2  2  3  3
15  2  3  2  2  1
16  2  1  2  2  3
17  2  3  3  1  2
18  2  1  3  1  3
.....
```

How can I calculate the probability of the whole sequence of the row just having the first integer and update looking at the second and the third etc...

**More info**

There is no dependency between each row and each column but 
I have the probability of each integer (1,2,3) to be in each column : `1 (0.2) 2 (0.2) 3 (0.6)` and the probability of each unique series in a row is:

```
11223 0.01 
12311 0.01 
13121 0.01 
13233 0.01
13313 0.01 
13323 0.01 
......... 
33233 0.02 
33313 0.01 
33323 0.01 
33331 0.01 
33332 0.03 
33333 0.16
```

Each draw is independent from previous draw. 
Instead of integers 1 2 3 I should talk about A B and C to avoid confusion ...
this is a categorical Bayesian probability (I think :-) )

Comment: Can you confirm that how i have formatted your data is correct please

Comment: the format is correct

Comment: ok. good. I find your question a little unclear  - are there dependencies between the columns - ie why would the probability of the  value that the second column takes depend on the first? Can you add the answer (and show how it is calculated) for the first couple of rows please

Comment: Unfortunately there is no dependency between each row and each column but I have the probability of each integer (1,2,3) to be in each column :
1 (0.2)   2 (0.2)   3 (0.6)
and the probability of each unique series in a row es: 

11223   0.01   
12311   0.01   
13121   0.01
13233   0.01
13313   0.01
13323   0.01
.........  
33233  0.02
33313  0.01
33323  0.01
33331  0.01
33332  0.03
33333  0.16

Comment: Each draw is independent  from previous draw. Instead of integers 1 2 3 I should talk about A B and C to avoid confusion ...this is a categorical Baysian probability (I think :-) )

Comment: Sorry, I'm still dont understand so I'm not going to be any help . You may have more luck getting an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions as, *I think*, the question in its present state probably needs stats advice rather than programming.